# FBJS - Wall feed posting

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I am posting to a users wall feed using the correct permissions, however... none of his friends can see the posts made from my application... Why is this... I noticed a friend of mine has a subscribe button and only when I changed that to all updates does the post from my app on his wall show up on my news feed...

how can I make it that my app posts to his wall and is visible to all his friends..

Cheers

Phil

Comment: just so you know I am asting for the publish_stream permissions

Answer (score 0):

It is user's choice, and he can change it as they want.

http://phpcode.eu/images/1319552221.png

Comment: I don't even get that :S, is there something I am missing?

[link](https://www.heroapps.co.za/Untitled-2.png)

Comment: @Philip This is really strange. What URL exactly you see when facebook asks these permissions?

Comment: @This is what I see

(www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2FappNameHere%2F&response_type=code&canvas=1&perms=read_stream%2Cpublish_stream)

Comment: Never mind, I see it now... it seems that you don't get that selection fieled if you are on a test user...